# What happens if a photon emitted from an electron hits a positron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, electrons, polarization, antimatter

Assume electron and positron are free particles, I think the emitted photon will become left or right circularly polarized depending on the sources. Am I just being paranoid or does the photon care about charges(parity)?

Comment: Free electrons do not emit "real" photons. They must be interacting with something for emission to occur.

Comment: Dear Lewis Miller, what about an accelerating electron?